# Error 0xc0000225 after Hyper-V Role Install Win 2012 - A Required device isn't connected or can't be accessed

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

So I got a new Lab computer which I installed Windows 2012 (non-R2) on.  It is a Lenovo 9080 Eraser X315.  It is just a random gaming PC.  Whenever I try to install the Hyper-V Role on it, I get the Windows Boot Manager pop-up and it no longer lets me boot into Windows, displaying error 0xc0000225 (A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed).  I can still boot into safe mode, but it gets hung while trying to uninstall Hyper-V.  I did a decent amount of research online, and here are the steps that I tried, to no avail:

1. Full Re-Install from Scratch
2. Updated as many drivers as Windows 2012 would allow.
3. Disable USB Support on Motherboard
4. Updated BIOS
5. Checked AMD Virtualization Compatibility Tool (it checked out ok)
6. Completed All Available Windows Updates before installing Hyper-V

I am not sure what other solutions I can go through to get this working.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you install Windows Server 2012 on a consumer PC? Why not install Windows 10 and install Hyper-V under Windows 10?

Comment: Its just a lab pc, im using for testing and down have a server sitting around.